# Choosing column with NSExpression in CoreData

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, core-data

I have an object with two columns: updatedAtServer & updatedAtLocal.

When updatedAtServer exists it should be used, otherwise fall back to updatedAtLocal.

I want to do a query to find the maximum timestamp with this fallback logic but can't figure out how.

In SQL, I guess you could use the CASE function inside the MAX function:

```
MAX(CASE WHEN updatedAtServer IS NOT NULL THEN updatedAtServer ELSE updatedAtLocal END)
```

How can I solve this with CoreData?

Comment: What would your SQL query look like?  How would **you** solve this in SQL then you can work backwards from there.

Answer (score 0):

One perhaps not purist but practical solution is to do two queries. This should not impact performance because subqueries etc. tend to result in multiple trips to the store as well.

Demonstrating with in-memory predicates

```
NSArray *noServerUpdated = [allItems filteredArrayUsingPredicates:
  [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"updatedAtServer = NULL"];
NSArray *serverOrLocal = [allItems filteredArrayUsingPredicate:
  [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"not IN %@", noServerUpdated];
NSArray *serverUpdated = [serverOrLocal filteredArrayUsingPredicate:
  [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"updatedAtServer >= updatedAtLocal"];
NSArray *localUpdated = [[serverOrLocal filteredArrayUsingPredicate:
  [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"not IN %@", serverUpdated]
    arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:noServerUpdated];


NSNumber *maxServer = [serverUpdated valueForKeyPath:@"@max.updatedAtServer"];
NSNumber *maxLocal = [localUpdated valueForKeyPath:@"@max.updatedAtLocal"];
NSNumber *max = [maxUpated compare:maxLocal] == NSOrderAscending ?
  maxLocal : maxUpated;
```

Maybe also check for empty results first.

Comment: Thanks for answering, but this will be wrong as I need to decide wether to use server or local on each object. So updatedAtLocal might be new on all objects while updatedAtServer is very old, then MAX should be the newest of all the old server time stamps as server time takes precedence on each object if present.

Comment: The way you described the problem is that server overrides local, which is exactly what above code does. Adapt the solution to your needs, but don't change the problem after you get the correct answer.

Comment: It overrides per object, not on the calculated max for each column. In my example I have the CASE within the MAX. Your solution is having the CASE surrounding two MAX operations. So you just interpreted the question a bit wrong, but please edit your response if you know the answer and I will gladly mark it as correct! :)